# Matlab series representation

Tags: matlab, function, series

I have an exercise in Matlab where it says that I have to find the value of `an` from the following series: `an= x-x^3/3+x^5/5-x^7/7+x^9/9` and so on WITHOUT using `while` or `for`. What is the function? The programmer gives a number `n` and the number `x` and i have to calculate the result. For example, if `n=3` and `x=2`, we get: `1-1^3/3+1^5/5`. Please help.

Comment: See [`polyval`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a vector of n-terms (`0:n-1`) and apply the general term (an) to that vector using element-by-element operations, and sum the result like this:

```
n = 3;     % Number of terms
x = 1;     % Value of x is given
N = 0:n-1; % Vector of n-terms
an = (-1).^(N) .* x.^(2*N+1) ./ (2*N+1);
sum(an)
```